# stop jwplayer 6 hiding controlbar

Tags: jwplayer, jwplayer6

I am using jwplayer 6, while the video is playing jwplayer hides the control bar and only if we pause the video its showing the control bar.

I tried setup options:

```
jwplayer("jwplayer").setup({
    file: "video/new.mp4",
    image: "img/common/download.jpg",       
    controls : true,
    controlbar.idlehide : false,
    width: 673,
    height: 400
});
```

But its throwing error.Is there any way to stop hiding the control bar.

Comment: It is not possible to always show the controlbar in JW6, it will always fade.

Comment: @EthanJWPlayer is there any hack to do that.I need only seek bar.

Comment: There is not any hack.

Comment: No problem, any time.

Answer (score 3):

You can add this to your CSS and should remain visible for the HTML5 Player:

```
.jwplayer .jwcontrolbar {
    display: inline-block !important;
    opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

For those who use flash (IE9 and below) I don't know of a solution other than writing your own plugin with custom controls which would take more time than it is worth (unless you just want a play/pause button?).

Comment: this worked for me in jw6 in chrome, but not for jw7...but it should be possible in jw7, just haven't figured out how yet. thanks justin!

Answer (score 1):

In jwplayer 6 it simply can't be done. Downgrade to jw5 and it will be do-able.

I think the guys at jwplayer are plain stupid. This, and other 'features' in the new jw6 such as the unchangeble vertical volume slider, etc. makes using this player almost impossible for the majority of us. Removing very old and used features from a product is like commiting suicide for a company. It didn't happen YET because there are not many alternatives for jw. Eventually there will be, so good luck with that amazingly clever business strategy, jw !

P.s. Beaware that the geniuses at jwplayer are no longer supporting jw5, so you will not find any documentation on that topic. Also the source code for older versions is also no longer available, giving the fact that they switched from their developers platform to github, and they "forgot" to migrate the old player files.

Good Luck

Answer (score 0):

While the update doesn't come with a plausible solution, we've got to make it work.

So, I did so:

```
var targetId = 'player';

$jwplayer(targetId).onReady(function(){

    this.onPlay(callbackOnPlay);

});

var callbackOnPlay = function(){

    var player = $('#' + targetId),
    controlbar = (player.length) ? player.find('.jw-controls') : $('.jw-controls');

    player.onPlay()

    if (player.length && controlbar.length) {

        //Delay 2s
        setTimeout(function() {
           controlbar.fadeOut();
        }, 2000);

        //Add hover event
        player.hover(
           function() {
              controlbar.fadeIn();
           }, function() {
              controlbar.fadeOut();
           }
        );

    }

};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JW Player 7.3 you can do this via JS:

```
   var playerInstance = jwplayer('player');
   playerInstance.setup({ ...your config…});

   playerInstance.onReady(function(){     
      displayControlBar();
   });

   function displayControlBar() {
      var controlBar = document.getElementsByClassName('jw-controlbar jw-background-color jw-reset')[0];
      controlBar.style.display = "block"
   }
```